# Magento - Magmi Import: skipped 1 record

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.4, magmi

I'm trying to get Magmi (Magento mass importer) working. On a test installation I want to import a CSV with one row of headers and one product item. I'm using the following CSV code:

```
"sku";"name";"price";"qty";"is_in_stock";"visibility";"image";"weight";"categories";"tax_class_id"
12333444;"T-Shirt White Small.";2.95;1;1;4;;"0.3";"shirts";2
```

When I import this, I get the following results back:

```
Performing Datasouce Lookup...
Found 1 records, took 0.00013017654418945 sec
CSV Datasource v1.2 - 10 CSV headers columns found
Ajusted processed columns:10

Global Stats
Imported    Elapsed     Recs/min    Attrs/min   Last 0.5%
1 items (100%)  0.001   61863   618630  0.0008

DB Stats
Requests    Elapsed     Speed   Avg Reqs    Efficiency  Last 0.5%   
1   0.0003  189360 reqs/min     1/item  30%     1 reqs

1 warning(s) found: Skus imported KO:1/1 
Runtime infos: Skus imported OK:0/1
Skipped 1 records
```

So nothing is imported, and I'm a bit lost on why. Is the CSV not correct? Should I add columns for the store? Where can I see error reports on the import?

---

SOLUTION

Based on dweeves answer...

- I removed the categories and tax_class_id column.
- I use the last version.
- I use the "create new items..." mode when running the import

Still, it didn't work. After some searching, I added the following columns:

- store = admin (the default value)
- attribute_set = ... (search for a value in the admin)
- type = simple (Simple Product)

Now the import works.

Comment: The problem was the store column. Attribute set and type may be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- for handling "categories" column, you need extra plugin package that has category importer.
- tax_class_id column should contain the label of the tax class (as in dataflow format)
- make sure you are using latest magmi (0.7.18 beta 2 or even better , latest svn snapshot)
- if sku does not exist in magento and you want to create it, use "create new & update existing mode", it sku already exists in magento , then "update existing" import mode should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added my solution to the question!

Comment: my error SKU Finder v0.0.1 - is not a valid attribute so how to set "create new & update existing mode",